# Can't see bootcamp anymore after OS X install

Tags: bootcamp, windows

My mac pro (first gen) previously had a whole disc dedicated to Windows/bootcamp. I've now added a new disk to the machine. On this new disk I have installed OS X 10.6.

Now when I boot the machine, it loads straight into OS X without offering me the Windows option. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the Boot Camp disk readable from OS X?  That's the first step. After making sure that your Mac can actually read the disk,

- Hold down <kbd>Option</kbd> while booting to show a boot menu, or
- Install [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/)